# Assign first date and last dates to a new variable

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset which contain 2 date fields (date1 and date2) , I have to create two new date fields where the date3 will be the earliest date in date1 and date4 will be date2 +31 days. And it has to be done grouped on testid.
Data that I have :

```
data have;
input acct_num test_id date1 date2 ;
DATALINES; 
55203610 1 2-feb-20    15-Apr-20
55203610 1 15-feb-20   15-Apr-20     
55203610 1 20-feb-20   15-Apr-20
55203610 2 1-Jan-20    20-May-20     
55203610 2 15-Mar-18   20-May-20
55203610 3 1-feb-17    1-Jul-20
;
run;

data want;
input acct_num test_id date1 date2 date3 date4;
DATALINES; 
55203610 1 2-feb-20    15-Apr-20   2-Feb-20   16-May-20
55203610 1 15-feb-20   15-Apr-20   2-Feb-20   16-May-20  
55203610 1 20-feb-20   15-Apr-20   2-Feb-20   16-May-20
55203610 2 1-Jan-20    20-May-20   15-Mar-18  20-Jun-20
55203610 2 15-Mar-18   20-May-20   15-Mar-18  20-Jun-20
55203610 3 1-feb-17    1-Jul-20    1-feb-17   1-Aug-20
;
run;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DoW Loop](https://sasnrd.com/sas-dow-loop-example/)

```
data want;
    do until (last.test_id);
        set have;
        by test_id;
        minval=min(minval, date1);
    end;

    do until (last.test_id);
        set have;
        by test_id;
        date3=minval;
        date4=date2 + 31;
        output;
    end;

    format date: date9.;
    drop minval;
run;
```